# Why after calling a function from an imported python file within a file the PyQt app stops responding?

Tags: python, import, scipy, pyqt, plotly

I have created a PyQt5 GUI in my **main**.py file which is in a main app folder. In the file for the interface, a button initiates a new class called Calculation (in the file entry.py) passing in the values of several inputs on the page and in this class the startCalculation() method is called. In this method, the different variables are passed to methods in imported python files, then the result of those calculation is returned and passed to the next calculation in another python file. These returns are in the form of arrays containing values (for the y axis which is then displayed using numpy and plotly).

When I run the app and click on the button in the main interface, the app starts loading (rainbow animation on Mac) and it says it is not responding. It is not a problem with the class itself as a normal print test works in the startCalculation() method, but the function from the imported file causes this to happen. Also, no errors are given in the terminal.

The following is code in the PyQt interface file (**main**.py)

```py
from app import entry

    def startButton(self):
        massaTotale = float(self.lineEdit.text())
        dragCoefficient = float(self.lineEdit_5.text())
        liftCoefficient = float(self.lineEdit_6.text())
        powerAvionics = float(self.lineEdit_3.text())
        powerPayload = float(self.lineEdit_4.text())
        airSpeed = float(self.lineEdit_8.text())
        valoreUnico = float(self.valoreUnicoEdit.text())
        engineEfficiency = float(self.lineEdit_9.text())
        turbolenceCoeff = float(self.lineEdit_10.text())
        dayOfYear = float(self.day_LineEdit.text())
        latitude = float(self.latitude_LineEdit.text())
        sunsetHourAngle = float(self.sunsetHourAngle_LineEdit.text())
        declination = float(self.declination_LineEdit.text())
        newCaluclation = entry.Calculation(massaTotale, dragCoefficient, liftCoefficient, powerAvionics, powerPayload, airSpeed, valoreUnico, engineEfficiency, turbolenceCoeff, dayOfYear, latitude, sunsetHourAngle, declination)
        newCaluclation.startCalculation()
```

And this is the code in the class calling the function in the external file

```py
from app.mainFunctions import pLevel

    #constructor method
    def __init__(self, massaTotale, dragCoefficient, liftCoefficient, powerAvionics, powerPayload, airSpeed, valoreUnico, efficiencyEngine, turbolenceCoeff, dayOfYear, latitude, sunsetHourAngle, declination):
        # calculate plevel
        self.totM = massaTotale
        self.vair = airSpeed
        self.cl = liftCoefficient
        self.cd = dragCoefficient
        self.efficiencyEngine = efficiencyEngine
        self.valoreUnico = valoreUnico
        self.powerAvionics = powerAvionics
        self.powerPayload = powerPayload
        self.turbolenceCoeff = turbolenceCoeff
        self.day_of_year = dayOfYear
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.sunset_hour_angle = sunsetHourAngle
        self.declination = declination

    #starting the calculation
    def startCalculation(self):

        self.x_values, self.pLevel_values = pLevel.calculate_pLevel(self.valoreUnico, self.cd, self.cl, self.totM)

        '''
        self.pEngine_values = pEngine.calculate_pEngine(self.x_values, self.pLevel_values, self.efficiencyEngine, self.turbolenceCoeff)
        self.pOut_values = pOut.calculate_pOut(self.x_values, self.pEngine_values, self.powerAvionics, self.powerPayload)
        self.I_loctime = I_loctime.calculate_I_loctime(self.day_of_year, self.latitude, self.sunset_hour_angle, self.declination)
        self.asm_values = area_Solar_Module.calculate_asm(self.x_values, self.pOut_values, self.I_loctime)
        '''
```

The pLevel.py file has the following code in it and should return the array of values to pass to the second function in the entry Calculation class file.

```py
import math
import numpy as np

import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import ipywidgets as widgets
import plotly.io as pio

import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
pio.renderers.default = "browser"

# calculating pLevel
x_values = []
y_values = []

layoutPLevel = go.Layout(
    title="pLevel",
    yaxis=dict(
        title='pLevel'
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        title='Surface Area Wing'
    )
)

def calculate_pLevel(valoreUnico, cd, cl, totM):
    x_values = []
    count = 0
    while (count < 5):
        x_values.append(count)
        count = count + 0.01

    y_values = []
    iteration = 0
    while (iteration < len(x_values)):
        x_value = x_values[iteration]
        if (x_value == 0):
            y_value = 0
            y_values.append(y_value)
        else:
            if (valoreUnico == 0.0):
                # nessun dato per valoreUnico dato, utilizza i due valori separati
                y_value = firstPart(cd, cl) * math.sqrt(secondPart(x_value, totM))
                y_values.append(y_value)
            else:
                y_value = valoreUnico * \
                math.sqrt(secondPart(x_value, totM))
                y_values.append(y_value)

            iteration = iteration + 1
    else:
        yNpArray = np.array(y_values)
        xNpArray = np.array(x_values)
        tracePLevel = go.Scatter(
            x=xNpArray,
            y=yNpArray,
            mode='lines',
            name='pLevel',
            line=dict(
                shape='spline'
            )
        )
        figPLevel = go.Figure(data=[tracePLevel], layout=layoutPLevel)
        figPLevel.show()
        return x_values, y_values


def firstPart(cd, cl):
    return (cd / cl**(3/2))


def secondPart(x_value, totM):
    return (2*(totM * 9.81)**3) / (1.225 * x_value)
```

The structure of the files is as follows:

```
-app
   -- __main__.py
   -- entry.py
   -- __init__.py
   -- mainFunctions
      --- pLevel.py
      --- __init__.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop for the x_values in the pLevel function was not adding one to the iteration so the loop went on forever. I just did not notice my error.

Instead of being

```
 while (iteration < len(x_values)):
    x_value = x_values[iteration]
    if (x_value == 0):
        y_value = 0
        y_values.append(y_value)
```

It should be

```
while (iteration < len(x_values)):
    x_value = x_values[iteration]
    if (x_value == 0):
        y_value = 0
        y_values.append(y_value)
        iteration = iteration+1
```